# Jacoco does not generate xml file

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am working with kotlin using gradle. And now I need to improve the code and I am using the sonarqube with jacoco. But my coverage is always at 0.0%.
My gradle:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"
    id("org.sonarqube") version "2.8"
    jacoco
    `maven-publish`
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()      
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000")
        property("sonar.language", "kotlin")
        property("sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8")
        property("sonar.projectName", "Commons.Pulsar")
        property("sonar.projectKey", "Aries.kt")
        property("sonar.projectVersion", "0.0.1")
        property("sonar.sources", "src/main/kotlin/")
        property("sonar.junit.reportPaths", "src/test/kotlin/")
        property("sonar.login", "admin")
        property("sonar.password", "admin")
        property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "build/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml")
    }
}

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}

tasks {
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        testLogging {
            events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
        }
    }
    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

but I noticed that jacocoTestReport.xml is not created. No xml is created.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Does putting the jacocoTestReport block outside of the tasks block work?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths` property, you only need to ensure that the task `jacocoTestReport` is executed before the `sonarqube` target. The sonarqube gradle plugin is smart enough to detect the configuration based on the jacoco report. As an example i link the [Junit Pioneer build configuration](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer/blob/master/build.gradle.kts), where we also do the same.

Generally speaking the sonarqube gradle plugin is quiet powerful, and if you utilize all the builds with gradle your sonarqube block only needs to look like this

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000")
        property("sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8")
        property("sonar.login", "admin")
        property("sonar.password", "admin")
    }
}
```

as it will detect the rest from your gradle configuration, as described in the [sonarqube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/)